# Reformat and build a string of consecutive numbers

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

I have string I want to format with consecutive numbers , what i have done is

```
int i =0 

String res = String.Foramt("text {0}  text {1} {2} {3} {4} ...", i
         ,i+1 , i+2, i+3, i+4)
```

is there a more elegant way of doing this , using Regex or Linq string manipulations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string res2 = string.Format(
            "text {0}  text {1} {2} {3} {4} ...", 
            Enumerable.Range(0, 5).OfType<object>().ToArray());
```

[string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes object array argument.

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx;

Answer (score 4):

There are many different ways to do that, but I think

```
String.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(0, 4))
```

is elegant enough for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In what sense? It produces a String with numbers separate by spaces. You can just pass it to your String.format as last argument.